# Ant Design input Issue for v-decorator and v-model showing database records for update in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, antd, ant-design-pro

Hi all kindly enlighten me how to fix these issues.
Issue 1. a-input v-decorator="['name']" initialValue="record.name"> Does not show the data from database  in input but can edit the value once entered something and submitted the form. here is my complete html code

```
<a-input v-decorator="['name']" initialValue="record.name" @input="record.name = $event.target.record.name"/>
```

Issue 2. I replace the "v-decorator" with v-model="record.name" and it works, the data is available inside a-input for editing BUT once form is submitted the value is not passed to "this.form" function because name of input does not exist. here is my complete html code

```
<a-input v-model="record.name" name="name" @input="record.name = $event.target.record.name"/>
```

Possible answers

```
1. how to set the "initial value" inside v-decorator for updating the value?
2. how to set "name" of input when using v-model which is already populated with record from database?
```

anybody here who has knowledge with ant design in vue js? I need help

Answer (score 0):

you can use initialValue in the options object for `v-decorator`

```
                 <a-form-item>
                    <a-input
                        v-decorator="[
                          'name',

                          { initialValue: user.email, rules: [{ type: 'name', required: true, message: 'Please use a valid name.' }] },
                        ]"
                        placeholder="Name"
                    >
                        <a-icon slot="prefix" type="mail" style="color:rgba(0,0,0,.25)" />
                    </a-input>
                    </a-form-item>
```

Comment: That is not working for me :(